# Laravel phpUnit Test Error with more than one function int he Test class

Tags: unit-testing, laravel

My test class is very simple

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/');

    }

    // when I add this, I get an error
    public function testAnotherExample()
    {
        $this->visit('profile');

    }
}
```

When I only have the "testBasicExample" method, the test runs fine. However, as soon as I add "testAnotherExample", the test fails with following error message.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare formatBytes() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\helpers\functions.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\helpers\functions.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:749
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(154): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(79): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 749
```

The same test if I comment out the "testBasicExample", then the other test works just fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `helpers\functions.php` looks like your own file. How are you loading it, and what does it contain?

Comment: bingo! thanks for the scrutiny. it had some common functions. changing its include function from include to include_once resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit 5.3.2 above works just fine with Laravel 5.

You need to **Uninstall old phpunit** first.

```
sudo apt-get purge phpunit
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove phpunit
```

Then install PHPUnit 5.6.1 as below

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
phpunit --version
```

Now you can run **phpunit** !!!

Answer (score 0):

answer from @ceejayoz was that :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare formatBytes() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\helpers\functions.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab\helpers\functions.php on line 7
```

was the culprit.

However your solution elixir to go from include to include_once just checks that the include is only declare once which is the classic way to include files in procedural PHP.

I would recommend to autoload the file rather by changing your `composer.json` file. Just include the logic file path (from where composer.json file is) inside the autoload section

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["helpers\functions.php"]

},
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files